# What are the alternatives to Globals in Python using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, global

I am teaching a class and have been told to avoid global statements using Python and Tkinter. I don't want to teach Classes to my students yet

I know I can create all my entry boxes and labels out of a subroutine and my code will work, but this is just teaching a different bad practice

```
from tkinter import *

def print_name():
    print(entry_location.get())

def main():
    global main_window,entry_location
    main_window =Tk()
    Button(main_window, text="Print Name",command=print_name) .pack()
    entry_location = Entry(main_window)
    entry_location.pack()
    main_window.mainloop()

main()
```

This works with the global statement, but short of removing the code in main() from the subroutine is there an alternative?

Comment: you can pass what you need to functions: `def print_name(entry_location)`

Comment: `main_window`, at least, doesn't need to be a global variable.

Comment: There's no apparent reason why `print_name` can't be defined *inside* `main`.

Comment: Not teaching them star imports might also be a good idea. I know even the official docs use them for tkinter, but they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you can eliminate globals by registering a lambda function to the button; this lambda function collects te value in the entry, and passes it as a parameter to `print_name`.

```
import tkinter as tk

def print_name(text=''):   # <- now receives a value as parameter
    print(text)

def main():
    main_window = tk.Tk()
    entry_location = tk.Entry(main_window)
    tk.Button(main_window, text="Print Name", command=lambda: print_name(entry_location.get())).pack()
    entry_location.pack()
    main_window.mainloop()

main()
```

#### Note:

This answers the special case of your example; it is not a generic answer to eliminating globals entirely. Alternative approaches could be to place the variables needed globally in a dictionary, or a list, thus permitting their modification in the local spaces, but in the end, it might become more complicated than using a proper class.
As suggested by @AndrasDeak, it is better to avoid star imports.

Answer (score -2):

as phydeaux said, you can do this py simply passing the variables as parameters.

full ammended code shown below:

```
from tkinter import *

def print_name(entry_location):
    print(entry_location.get())

def main(main_window, entry_location):
    main_window =Tk()
    Button(main_window, text="Print Name",command=print_name) .pack()
    entry_location = Entry(main_window)
    entry_location.pack()
    main_window.mainloop()

main(main_window, entry_location)
```

Comment: `entry_location` isn't being passed to the function that needs it.

Comment: I have tried this code and it does not work, I get the error "NameError: name 'main_window' is not defined". It just changes to entry_location if I remove main_windows

Comment: You will need to make sure you have either defined or simply initiated the variable at the start of the program, a simple ( main_windows = " " ) will do.